# Solution of multiple materials

Tags: physical-chemistry

### Introduction

I'm trying to make some strawberry liqueur. The recipe I got says I should put alcohol, strawberries and sugar in a bowl and leave it soaking for 4-5 weeks. I read that making liqueur is not a chemical reaction, but only a solvent (mostly alcohol) acting on some fruit, herb or nut. So, intuitively, I would add the sugar only after the soaking time. I wonder if that makes a difference.

### Question

If I dissolve material A in alcohol until it reaches saturation, how much of material B can I still dissolve in the solution?

- Nothing
- As much as with pure alcohol
- Something in between

None of the materials are gaseous and both are soluble in alcohol.

Comment: Will solve independently. $K_{sp}$ is the only factor affecting,unless there is a common ion in both A,B

Comment: One for [chemistry.SE]?